# Getting Search results to items I don't have access or permissions for

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, search-results, enterprise-search

I was a site collection administrator on all site before. When I remove myself from that permission and do a search, I get results for sites I no longer have access to.

So search isn't security trimming the results as I'd expect? Any reason?

Im on 2016 standard

Comment: What happens when you click on an item? Can you view it, or do you get 
an access denied message?

Comment: Access denied. Essentially we're removing permission right away and checking search. Most people are saying it's a crawling issue and that does make the most sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at your search crawl schedule -you might need to wait until the next crawl has finished after you changed your permissions.

Comment: I understand that but I thought trimming would be done at real time?

Comment: Harry is right; IF it was real-time then why would a Crawler be needed?

Comment: Good point. I guess we'll have to update the crawl schedule to managed these changes faster

Comment: This is one reason Continuous Crawl is better. Security changes are picked up and processed much faster and more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

Please do have incremental call for that particular site collection and see it will helpful.